# Manipulate list

Tags: list-manipulation, homework

Make a Manipulate to display a column of integer powers with bases from 1 to 25 and exponents from 1 to 10.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[
  Table[25^n, a]],
 {n, 1, 25, 1}, {a, 1, 10, 1}]
```

this is the best I can do. need help...

Comment: You meant to write `Table[Table[n^a, {n, 1, 25}], {a, 1, 10}]` instead of what you have, right?

Comment: Maybe `Manipulate[n^a, {n, Range[25]}, {a, Range[10]}]`

Comment: Or `Grid[Table[n^a, {n, Range[25]}, {a, Range[10]}], Frame -> All]`?

Comment: In a `Manipulate` something (a variable) is *CHANGED*.  But not in your request.  Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this works.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[Table[n^b, {b, 1, a}]], {n, 1, 25, 1}, {a, 1, 10, 1}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```